# Silverlight Datagrid New Row Goes to Bottom and Screws Up Multi-Delete Logic

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, datagrid

I have a Silverlight 4 application I've been tasked with making some changes to. I'd rather redo it in something supported, but that's not an option at the moment. I have a datagrid and I've added a button to insert a new row into the datagrid and database table using the values from two comboboxes:

```
Private Sub btnAddAccountGroupLink_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAddAccountGroupLink.Click
    Dim sv_ag As Com_AccountGroup = cbACCT_GROUP.SelectedValue
    Dim sv_cf As CS_FUND = cbACCT_CD.SelectedValue

    AccountGroupLinkData.DataView.Add(New Com_AccountGroupLink() With {.ACCT_GROUP = sv_ag.ACCT_GROUP, .ACCT_CD = sv_cf.ACCT_CD})
    AccountGroupLinkData.SubmitChanges()

End Sub
```

When the row is added, it gets added to the bottom of the datagrid instead of it's properly sorted location. This also breaks my code that deletes selected indexes from the datagrid:

```
Private Sub btnRemoveSelected_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnRemoveSelected.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the selected records?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) = MessageBoxResult.OK Then
        Dim indexesToDelete As New List(Of Integer)

        For i As Integer = 0 To AccountGroupLinkData.DataView.Count - 1
            If AccountGroupLinkData.DataView(i).IsSelected Then
                indexesToDelete.Add(i)
            End If
        Next i

        For d As Integer = 0 To indexesToDelete.Count - 1
            AccountGroupLinkData.DataView.RemoveAt(0)
        Next d

        AccountGroupLinkData.SubmitChanges()

    End If

End Sub
```

So if I delete the bottom row, it actually deletes the row that's located where this row should be.

How can I force the datagrid to update or show the row in its correct position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding this code after the SubmitChanges:

```
NavigationService.Refresh()
```

This refreshes the Silverlight page and the row pops up to the proper position.